# my Java and Arraylists aren't playing nice

Tags: java, arraylist

How would you put the result of the following iteration into an ArrayList along with other objects. Note that the ArrayList is of type "Shape" which is an abstract class

```
    for(int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++){            

        for(int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++) {

            if(row==0 || col==0) {
                System.out.print(borderCharacter + " ");
            }               
            else if(row == numberOfRows - 1 || col == numberOfColumns - 1) {
                System.out.print(borderCharacter + " ");
            }               
            else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }               
        } //close col forLoop

        System.out.println();

    } // close row forLoop
```

Also this for an assignment so we have been instructed to use ArrayLists or LinkedLists (only been programming for 2-3 months all up)

Comment: I dont know what kind of shapes do you want in your array? Also I think I would use the "add" method of `ArrayList` to add my shapes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what "put the result of the following iteration" means, but if you want to match your iteration (over what appears to be matrix), then you'll need a two dimensional array, hence an `ArrayList` of an `ArrayList` containing `Shape`. So declaration like this: `ArrayList<ArrayList<Shape>> myMatrix`.

If you don't need the structure then just use `ArrayList<Shape>`.

As this is an assignment I'll leave you to work out the rest i.e. how to add elements into your `ArrayList` etc. Check the Java Doc on the `List` interface [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Hint: If you have a 2-dimensional `ArrayList`, don't forget to initialise each `ArrayList` in the containing `ArrayList`.